# Error: Invalid key length in use crypto.createDecipheriv

Tags: node.js, cryptography, base64, aes

I want to use aes-128-cbc to decode , but it goes to Invaid key length, what's the matter?

below is the code :

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var key = 'DoCKvdLslTuB4y3EZlKate7XMottHski1LmyqJHvUhs'+'=';
var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16) //key.substr(0,16)
var keyhex = new Buffer(key,'base64').toString('hex')
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc',keyhex,iv)
```

next is the error report:
crypto.js:267
  this._handle.initiv(cipher, toBuf(key), toBuf(iv));
               ^

```
Error: Invalid key length
    at new Decipheriv (crypto.js:267:16)
    at Object.createDecipheriv (crypto.js:627:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sheen/workspace/app/base64.js:8:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

How can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up binary and hexadecimals. Hexadecimals is a *textual representation* or *encoding* of bytes.

Your key is 32 bytes / 256 bits in size after base 64 decoding. However, then you create a hexadecimal representation of it consisting of 64 characters. These get translated into bytes again, so now your key is 64 bytes / 512 bits in size - and that's an invalid key size.

To use binary, just remove `.toString('hex')` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `secretKey` has string of length *32*. In my case, I changed it to something else, and it was causing this "Invalid key length" error:

```
const cipher = createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv);
```